# .htaccess rewrite adding email

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi I recently made a webshop, however when I receive an invoice I want it on online however hidden from others.

At the moment my .htaccess looks like following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9\.+-]+)(|/)$ invoice.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

This makes my URL look like. www.domain.com/(id) example, www.domain.com/5.

This makes it easy to look up others invoice. So I was thinking of adding payer email to it, so it would look like

www.domain.com/(payer-email)/(id).

Could you help me what my .htaccess would look like? :)

Comment: https://www.addedbytes.com/download/?file=mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet-v2/png/ :)

Comment: i cant really figure it out. Could you maybe help me with the specific code? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be working for me :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^invoice/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ invoice.php?email=$1&id=$2 [L,NC]
```

www.domain.com/invoice/toto@gmail.com/20 will lead to www.domain.com/invoice.php?email=toto@gmail.com&id=20